# Switch out site images daily

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3

So, we are going to be creating a view that has interchangeable images.

Basically, this process is automated to the point where we can log on to the admin site, click a button, and that button grabs the next set of images and changes the `src` attribute of all the images already on the page.

Problem is, we want this to run daily every 24 hours, but I'm not sure how to set that up. MVC is stateless, so we wouldn't be able to put a timer in the controller, and if we had say a SQL Job setup, I'm not sure how the site would be notified of that event - if that route is even possible.

What's one way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the paths from SQL Server inside the controller every time you request the page.

Comment: I can do this but, what if someone requests the page right before the period switches over, and then it switches for everyone else, and they're looking at something incorrent?

Comment: That's html for you, already old before it even reaches the client. On the next page request he'll get the new images.

Comment: There is (almost) no way that you can possibly fix that.  (Unless you can figure out that it changed in Javascript)

Comment: Yeah I was afraid this was the case. I guess when the user accesses something on the "old" version, we'll maybe just check the images, check the date, and if it's a mismath - we'll notify them and re-direct them or something...

Comment: @SLaks - yeah we'd have to setup a front end javascript timer that runs frequently as the user is navigating the page. Which might be the way to do it...

Comment: @slandau: When the user loads the next page, they'll get the new images naturally.  You don't need to do anything.

Comment: @slandau: Incidentally, the problem you mention already exists with your current button method... So it really shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @Chris - your right, lol. That's why I posted here to try and solve the problem. But I guess there's no way to do it besides going through Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you change the `src` tags... You know what the date is in your controller, just pass the images to the view inside your model (create a view model if you're only sending an array of items).

Comment: Well yeah we'll probably do it that way, hasn't been made yet. I was more looking for an answer about how we can time the switch.

Comment: @slandau: I think you've taken a very simply thing and overly complicated it.

Answer (score 0):

Have your ASP.NET script set the `src` attributes dynamically:

```
<img id="place1" src="<%
int day = DateTime.Now.Day;
string[] images = {"images/image1_place1.jpg", "images/image2_place1.jpg", "etc.jpg"};

Response.Write(images[day % images.Length]);
%>" />
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: @SLaks: Well, that's something along those lines :)